# Number of tiles is less than the number of points after running voronoi tessellation in R

Tags: r, voronoi, tessellation

I have generated a voronoi tessellation for the district of Bankura in West Bengal using the code,

```
India <- getData("GADM", country = "India", level = 2)
wb1 <- subset(India, NAME_1 == "West Bengal")
bankura <- subset(wb1,NAME_2=="Bankura")
voronoipolygons <- function(x, poly) {
library(deldir)
if (.hasSlot(x, 'coords')) {
crds <- x@coords  
} else crds <- x
bb = bbox(poly)
rw = as.numeric(t(bbox(poly)))
z <- deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2],rw=rw)
w <- tile.list(z)
polys <- vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
require(sp)
for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
pcrds <- cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
pcrds <- rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
polys[[i]] <- Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
}
SP <- SpatialPolygons(polys)

 SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
 SP, data.frame(data=data.frame(dummy = seq(length(SP)), 
               row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
                                function(x) slot(x, 'ID')))))  
}
tess_prim <- voronoipolygons(prim_school, bankura)
proj4string(tess_prim) <- proj4string(bankura)
final_prim <- gIntersection(bankura, tess_prim, byid=TRUE)
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "red","yellow"))
plot(final_prim, col=pal(length(final_prim)), border="black")
points(prim_school, pch=20)
```

Here the file prim_school is the latitude and longitude information of primary schools in the district. The problem is that there are 2336 observations in the file. But when I am checking the tiles created as part of voronoi tessellation the number of tiles are 2309. Why is this happening? Why are the number of polygons less than the number of observations?

Comment: `spatstat` offers a way to examine relation between point and voronoi, (which point to which voronoi)  help(cut.ppp) [stat.ethz.ch](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2009-October/006637.html) as starting point, perhaps.

Comment: Thank You for the link. But could you please suggest how do I actually use the cut.ppp function to get the relation between point and voronoi tiles.

Comment: To help others it would help if you put your full code including libraries, I'm assuming you're using `library(raster)` for `raster::getData(GDAM`, but don't know where your points for primary schools come from, so can't at the moment help with cut.ppp except to say `library(spatstat), X <- as.SpatialPoints.ppp(from = your primary), Y<- as.SpatialPolygons.tess(tess_prim)`, but again, don't have the primary school points data, so you might edit your above to reveal your full pipeline.

Comment: Thank You for the help. I could work this out.

Comment: Then answer your own question both to explain and help others.